# Ошибка missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' при POST запросе Flask

Tags: python, json, post, flask

Нужно принять и обработать post запрос на flask
 Функция принимающая запрос:

```
@app.route('/zapros', methods=['POST'])
def zapros():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        if data['event'] == 'login':
            print(data)
            return Response(status=200)
        else:
            print("error")
            return Response(status=500)
        return Response(status=200)
```

отправляю запрос

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"event":"login"}' https://localhost:5000/zapros
```

ответом получаю 500
и  ошибку

```
zapros() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Почему требуется аргумент request?

Comment: `def zapros(request):` напишите. Почему требуется запрос? Чтобы его обработать...

Comment: не поможет, пробовал. тот же ответ

Comment: Вы случайно не забыли перезагрузить сервер после внесения изменений в код?

Comment: точно) как я мог

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте параметр `request` в определение функции:

```py
def zapros(request):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zapros() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

говорит о том, что ожидается аргумент request, который в функцию не передаётся.

Хочу напомнить, что в Flask необходимо импортировать `request` (добавлять в аргументы функции не нужно, то есть приведённый вами код верен, но на post запрос можно не проверять, flask не-post не пропустит):

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/zapros', methods=['POST'])
def zapros():
    if request.method ...
```

И потом просто в теле функции использовать `request`.

Также nomnoms12 верно подметил, что надо не забывать перезапускать сервер, либо активировать режим дебага:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Если решение помогло, пометьте ответ правильным, чтобы закрыть вопрос